# Are separability and ccc equivalent for closed subspaces of $\beta N$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ultrafilters, stone-cech-compactification

Let $\beta \mathbb N$ be the Stone-Cech compactification of the integers. Then $\beta \mathbb N\setminus \mathbb N$ is non-separable because if fails the ccc condition, that is, it has an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open sets.

Are separability and ccc equivalent for a closed subset of $\beta \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 6):

No. There is a [compactification of $\mathbb{N}$](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0464.54017) whose remainder, $K$, is ccc non-separable. So there is a continuous surjection $f$ from $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ onto $K$; take a closed subset $F$ such that $f$ is irreducible on $F$. Then $F$ is a ccc non-separable subspace of $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$.